# How to proper read this SML function that uses foldl?

Tags: sml, smlnj, mlton

I am new to SML and I am having trouble understanding what are arguments and what is being passed to the inner function in this code.

```
fun print_mat mat =                                                              
  let                                                                            
    val _ = (Array.foldl (                                                       
        fn (arr, _) =>                                                           
          let val _ = (print_arr arr) in () end                                  
    ) () mat)                                                                    
  in () end;
```

Which is meant to be used in:

```
val mat = 
  Array.fromList[                                                                
                 (Array.fromList [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]),                              
                 (Array.fromList [1, 0, 1, 0, 0])                             
                ]

val _ print_mat mat
```

What I am failing to see is how the `arr` gets selected from my `mat` and used inside the closure function.

Comment: Do you understand what `foldl` does?

Comment: It applies the function (`fn (arr, _) => ...`  to every element of the Array data structure.

Comment: This code is overcomplicated. You should be able to shorten it to `fun print_mat mat = Array.foldl (fn (arr, _) => print_arr arr) () mat`, which might make it easier to read. Or in fact just `fun print_mat mat = Array.app print_arr mat`, because the fold is not needed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foldl` does something more than apply `fn (arr, _) => ...` to every element. It *accumulates* a result, which in your case is discarded with the wildcard pattern, `_`, in favor of the unit value, `()`. So, as Andreas Rossberg points out, you're not actually accumulating anything, or even generating any result value, so `Array.app` is better suited.

To understand what

```
fun print_mat mat = Array.app print_arr mat
```

does, you can look at [its implementation](https://github.com/kfl/mosml/blob/master/src/mosmllib/Array.mlp#L163):

```
fun app f a =
    let val a = from_array a
    val stop = length_ a
    fun lr j = if j < stop then (f(sub_ a j); lr (j+1))
           else ()
    in lr 0 end
```

Meaning, it calls `f` (in your case `print_arr`) on the 0th row of `a` (in your case `mat`), then on the 1st row, then on the 2nd until there are on more rows. When there are no more rows, return `()`. In the meantime, you have done nothing superfluous such as accumulate some value, since it will always be `()` that you return when done anyway.

I wonder if you have seen that [Array2](http://sml-family.org/Basis/array2.html) exists. It should be pretty ideal for matrices.

As for understanding folding, see [ML for the Working Programmer, ch. 5: *Functions and infinite data*](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~lp15/MLbook/pub-details.html).

I recommend that you understand folding in a list context first.

This is also what's best covered in learning material.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I was not aware of the type of `( )`. I also appreciate the links. Here my `fn` does not return anything, thus it is best for me to use `Array.app` as I am not doing any folds. With regards to `(Array.foldl (fn) () mat)` From the implementation, now I understand that it requires 3 arguments. For future reference the second argument - that I passed `( )` - has to match the return type of `fn`, and it is the value being aggregated after the fold function `fn` is applied to each element of the `Array` data strucuture.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Good job!